# How important is it to watch vitamin K2 levels?

Tags: veganism, vitamins-and-minerals, scientific-studies

I've read an article arguing about the importance of vitamin K2 for correct calcium management in the body.

There is danger of having low vitamin K2 in a vegan diet.

How important is it to watch levels of this vitamin and is it recommended for vegans to supplement it?

Comment: could you link the article you are referring to? It would help me better understand the issue with a low vegan K2 diet

Answer (score 3):

*provisionnal answer in wait for access to the referred article*

According to wikipedia on vitamin [K2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin_K#Dietary_recommendations) and [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin_K2#Dietary_intake_in_humans) the European Food Safety Authority set an "Adequate Intakes" at 70 micrograms a day for vitamin K.

Again according to wikipedia, you can get vitamin K2 out of [natto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natt%C5%8D).

The use of an "Adequate Intakes" instead of a recommended dietary allowances and no discrimination between K1 and K2 is due to a lack of evidence when they established their standards.

Therefore, to answer your question, I wouldn't panic about vitamin K2 as research is not being conclusive (yet! I'm curious about your article).

In case of doubt/symptoms, go see a doctor.

Comment: I don't remember what the original article was, but here's what I think is the primary source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4566462/

As for natto, I'm, unfortunately, allergic to soy, so it's a no-go for me.

Comment: Follow-up: I asked my doctor but I didn't get more information on this

Comment: @bernardpaulus: According to wiki, dairy products, such as cheese, butter milk, butterr, etc, contain K2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin_K2#Dietary_sources)

Comment: @srimannarayanakv yes, right - but please note that this question is framed in a vegan approach. Vegetarian but non-vegan sources of K2 like cheese. butter and so on are thus out of scope. Please don't hesitate to share if you have more info about the health problems due to a lack of  K2 :)

Comment: @bernardpaulus: I agree that from Vegan point of view what you stated is right.:-).  From a vegetarian point of view, that I am, milk and milk products are acceptable.